# Reverse proxy failing to load assets correctly

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy, which I wrote. It simply intercepts requests to validate auth then forwards to the origin server. The problem is that none of the assets are rendering properly, but the site loads.

## Prometheus Server (My application behind the reverse proxy)

[image]

Comparing the response data with and without my reverse proxy, I can see that when it works as expected, the `content-type` is different.

However, when I'm using the reverse proxy and I hit the links directly (i.e - the logo which isn't loading), I can get the image itself to render fine.

What could I be missing? I assume it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

```
// ReverseProxy is a blind forwarding reverse proxy that is intended to run
// after all registered middleware
func ReverseProxy(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // This represents the origin server, which would be loaded dynamically from the deployment config or
    // external environment variables, config map, secrets vault, etc
    for key, ele := range mw {
        fmt.Printf("Invoking middleware: %s\n", key)
        err := ele(w, req)
        if err != nil {
            unauthorizedPage(w, req)
            return
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n\n")

    // Maps to internal container host (multi-container pod)
    host := "localhost"
    port, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("POST_AUTH_TARGET_PORT"))

    originSvr, err := url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%d", host, port))
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprint(w, req)
        return
    }

    req.Header.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", req.Host)
    req.Header.Add("X-Origin-Host", originSvr.Host)

    req.Host = originSvr.Host
    req.URL.Host = originSvr.Host
    req.URL.Scheme = originSvr.Scheme
    req.RequestURI = ""

    originResp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprint(w, req)
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(originResp.StatusCode)
    io.Copy(w, originResp.Body)
}
```